# Windows 7 Master Boot Record issue

Tags: windows-7

Recently Windows 7 stopped working on my desktop. It displayed the "Reboot and select proper boot device" error message. I went through a few of the general fixes for this error message:

checked my BIOS to make sure I was trying to boot off the correct drive (I was). I also unplugged all my other drives so that the only one available is the OS drive. Still no luck.

tried to use the Windows installation disk. Just ended up getting an error message "System Recovery options is not compatible with the version of Windows you are trying to repair..." when trying to use system recovery.

Next, I booted up my computer using a bootable CD of Linux Mint I had around. I tried to use Boot Repair, however it did not even show the option to repair. It did however give me this information. Can someone smarter than me look at this data from Boot Repair: http://paste2.org/jy4EwnpU

Do you think it is the MBR that is bad or the hard drive or something else? Could it be my motherboard? How would I test that? I am almost ready to just completely wipe the drive and start over at this point but I figured somebody out there might be able to help. Let me know if there is a better place for me to post my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is causing the problem, but if you are having a Linux Mint Live CD, good. Take the CD, have an external Hard Disk with you, connect the hard disk, boot to the live CD, press the Try option, copy all the your files to the External Hard Drive, reinstall Windows, and just recover from the External HD. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem might be but you can try repairing MBR and see if it works.

To repair MBR and restore Windows 7 boot loader follow these steps:

1. Boot form Windows installation disk and choose *Repair Your Computer*.
2. Select correct Windows installation and you will be prompted with System Recovery Options screen. Select Command Prompt.
   [image]
3. Use following commands to restore MBR: `bootrec /fixmbr`
4. Or rewrite new boot sector on system partition: `bootrec /fixboot`
5. Reboot system and see if it works.

If repairing MBR doesn't work for you then maybe your installation is corrupted or drive is failing, I suggest you to take backup of data using some live CD and then reinstalling Windows.

Hope this helps you.